# If an IVP does not enjoy uniqueness, then it possesses infinitely many solutions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I am trying to prove that when an IVP in ODEs does not enjoy uniqueness, then it has infinitely many different solutions. I know that when the Lipschitz condition is satisfied, then there is a unique solution.

I guess, I am trying to show that if the IVP possesses two solutions, then we can create infinitely many solutions using these two. However, I am slightly lost as where to start the proof.

Answer (score 13):

This is not something totally trivial.

It is Helmut Kneser's Theorem.

Let the following IVP
$$
x'=f(t,x), \quad x(\tau)=\xi,\tag{1}
$$ 
where $x,f,\xi\in\mathbb R^n$.
Then the set for any $s\in\mathbb R$, for which there exists a solution of the above in the interval $[\tau,s]$ the set
$$
S=\{x(s): x\,\, \text{is a solution of $(1)$}\},
$$
is connected.

In the one-dimensional case, the proof is rather simple. Assume that $\varphi,\psi:[\tau,\sigma]\to\mathbb R$ are solutions of $(1)$ and $\varphi(\sigma)<\eta<\psi(\sigma)$. Then solve "backwards" the IVP
$$
x'=f(t,x), \quad x(\sigma)=\eta,\tag{2}
$$ 
which means that you obtain a solution $\zeta$ for $t\le \sigma$. As soon as the graph of $\zeta$ hits the graph of $\varphi$ or $\psi$, say at $t_0\in(\tau,\sigma)$ you have $\zeta(t_0)=\psi(t_0)$, then you can define a new solution $\tilde\zeta$ as
$$
\tilde\zeta(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{lll}
\psi(t) & \text{if} & t\in[\tau,t_0], \\
\zeta(t) & \text{if} & t\in[t_0,\sigma].
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
Clearly $\tilde\zeta$ satisfies both $(1)$ and $(2)$, and that's how you obtain a continuum of solutions.

For a more general theorem, see Philip Hartman, *Ordinary Differential Equations*, page 15.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I knew the theorem had a name, but I couldn't recall it.  So my question is the other answer I received shows that you can construct additional solutions from the non-uniqueness conditions, but does this imply there is a continuum of solutions?  Do I need to go through the proof of connectedness to show that it is indeed a continuum?

Comment: @user75514: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That was very helpful.

Comment: There is a late reply. Why the function $\zeta$ is defined in $[\tau ,\sigma]$? Or what's more important, why does its graph reach the line of function $\psi$ or $\phi$?

Comment: How do we know the new constructed soln is differentiable at $t_0$? Do you need some regularity conditions on $f$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis sir Kneser's Theorem holds even if function $f(t,x)$ is non continuous?

Comment: @neelkanth My guess is YES, since Caratheodory solutions are more general than the classical ones.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis thank you sir