# Exactly two solution of differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does there are differential equations of the form $y'=f(x,y),y(x_{0})=y_{0}$ which has exactly two solutions. Actually i have only differential equations which has either no solution or unique solutions or infinitely many solutions. Thanks.

Comment: There are always infinitely many solutions in the non-uniqueness case. The theorem is due to Kneser. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657284/if-an-ivp-does-not-enjoy-uniqueness-then-there-are-infinitely-many-solutions

Comment: Thanku...............