# How many solutions does an IVP of an ODE have, if it does not enjoy uniqueness?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be 2 different continuously differentiable functions in $[a,b]$, both of them solutions to the initial value problem

$$y'=F(x,y),$$
$$y(x_0)=y_0,$$
where $F$ is continuous.
Could these be the only 2 solutions of the IVP? If not, what is the minimum number of solutions of the above IVP?

I was looking for specific functions that could satisfy the demands but I feel like it wouldn't help me thoroughly prove prove what is needed. Any help? Thanks.

*It is a copy of a question I asked, now it is with $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Do you know if this is a linear ODE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an IVP possesses two solutions, then it possesses infinitely many solutions. In fact, it possesses a continuity of solutions!

See [If an IVP does not enjoy uniqueness, then there are infinitely many solutions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657284/if-an-ivp-does-not-enjoy-uniqueness-then-there-are-infinitely-many-solutions/657301#657301)