any method to know if an IVP has a unique solution, no solution or infinite solution without solving it?
Assume the IVP
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y), y(a)=b.$$
is there a way to know the nature of the solution without explicitly solving it?
what I tried if $f$ is Lipschitz, then it proves uniqueness.
But there is no way to know about infinite solution or no solution (as I know it, without solving). Can any one suggest a good reference in this direction?
Thank you

Peano's theorem assures the existence

@SineoftheTime so is it like its continuous but not Lipschitz implies infinite solutions?

If $f(x,y)$ is continuous, there's at least a solution, but this does not mean there are infinitely many.

If $f$ is continuous and $y'=f(x,y)$, $y(a)=b$ is not uniquely solvable, then it has infinite many solutions, see H. Kneser's Theorem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser%27s_theorem_(differential_equations) or here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657284/if-an-ivp-does-not-enjoy-uniqueness-then-it-possesses-infinitely-many-solutions/657301#657301

@Gerd, don't you have to first solve $y'=f(x,y)$ in order to determine whether $y(a)=b$ has more than one solution?

@Gonçalo You are right, if you want to apply Kneser's Theorem you have to know that there are at least two different solutions of the IVP. Then you know that it has an infinite number of solutions.
